# Tab Slider Android Studio not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I set up a tab slider in my activity calling 3 separate fragments depending on the fragment selected.  The problem is that when the first tab is selected, "Science" is shown - which was set on the onCreateView() method of the first fragment. However, WITHOUT clicking on the other tabs, "Technology" and "Sports" are then shown.

To my knowledge, the way I implemented it the last two should only show once the corresponding tab is selected.

This is my Page adapter class

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3; //Represents the number of tabs
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"Technology", "Science", "Sports"}; //Tab values defined in an array
    private Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context)
    {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    //determines the fragment depending on the selected tab
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        if(position==0)
            return TechnologyFragment.newInstance(position+1);
        else if(position==1)
            return ScienceFragment.newInstance(position+1);
        else if(position==2)
            return SportsFragment.newInstance(position+1);
        else
            return null;
    }

    //displays the title for each tab
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

This is the news class - where the view pager and tab layout are set up

```
public class News extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Here the viewPager is connected to the PagerAdapter class
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        //This component will be used to page between the various fragments created.
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), News.this));

        //the tabLayout is given the viewPager to connect to the pager with the tabs
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        //the following was used so the tabs fill up the width of the screen being responsive for all devices and orientations
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

    }

}
```

And these are the fragment classes - (the other two are identical but have a different message represented using the Toast)

```
public class ScienceFragment extends Fragment {

    //other methods

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_science_fragment, container, false);
        toShow=getAll();
        GridView gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getContext(),toShow));
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Science", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: So you want to show other tabs data only if they are clicked in the tablayout? What about setting their visibility and switch between visibility when a tab is clicked. A scenario like: Tab 1 is default so show it's data. User click tab 2 and Tab 1 data gets hide and Tab 2 data's visibility will switch to visible. Sorry if I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Yes exactly. I believe it's already implemented like that in the Page Adapter class in method getItem(). However, it is not working as desired

Comment: I don't see that function implemented in the getItem in your PagerAdapter class. It just set up views based on the clicked tab but it doesn't controls if the data should be shown or not. It just scroll between tabs when one of these is clicked. I think you should implement that function manually in the News activity class.